# I want my python code to start over again after the user has requested so or has given invalid input

Tags: python

I want the code to repeat itself if the user has given invalid input.
Another way to ask would be :

```
ans2 = input ('Do you want to continue (y/n)')
if ans2 == 'y':
#repeat the code and I don't know how to do that
if ans2 == 'n':
print ('Ok Goodbye')
exit
```

Comment: We would need more details including the actual code and what the "invalid input" could be. Right now, you don't mention the "first way", only "another way" where you're asking for y or n, which will both be valid, not invalid. So it's unclear what you actually mean.

Comment: The questioner wants the answer for the another way only

Comment: More details needed, but probably: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Comment: Also, you won't need `exit` at the end of the code because python quits automatically once the script has finished executing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1):

you can put it into loop

```py
while True:
    data = input("Enter data: ")

    if <valid_condition>:
        # do something
        ans2 = input('Do you want to continue (y/n)')
        if ans2 == "y":
            continue
        else:
            break
    else:
        print("Invalid data")
        ans2 = input('Do you want to continue (y/n)')
        if ans2 == "y":
            continue
        else:
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a fairly common structure.

```
def yourcode():
   pass  # your code here

ans2 = ''
while not ans2 in ['y','n']:
   ans2 = input ('Do you want to continue (y/n)')
   if ans2 == 'y':
      yourcode()
      ans2 = ''
   elif ans2 == 'n':
      print ('Ok Goodbye')
      exit
   else:
      print('Invalid response')
```

Comment: It does not work on the condition the questioner told

Answer (score -1):

You could define the code in function like below and you can call the function at the end and to repeated it again call it

```
def function():
    ans2 = input ('Do you want to continue (y/n)')
    if ans2 == 'y':
        function()
    if ans2 == 'n':
        print ('Ok Goodbye')
        sys.exit()
function()
```

Comment: Your answer does not fulfill questioner's requirement of "repeat itself".

Comment: It fullfils the requirement